# $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ having the same direction

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

Ohm's Law States that $\mathbf{J} = σ\mathbf{E}$ this implies then that $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{E}$ have the same direction .
But we know that $\mathbf{E}$ in normal to a conductor and $\mathbf{J}$ passes through the conductor (tangential) 
$\mathbf{J}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{s}$ will lead then to zero ?
What is the missing link ?

Comment: Charges flow along a wire under the influence of an electric field produced by a voltage source.  This movement of charge is a current whose direction is parallel to the electric field lines.  So J and E are in the same direction.  Your statement about electric field lines being perpendicular to the surface of a conductor is true  in the realm of electrostatics.where there are no electric field lines inside a conductor.

Comment: but if they are in the same direction then the integral to calculate I will be zero since E is normal to the conductor

Comment: E is *not* normal to the surface within the material.  There is a charge density gradient parallel to the surface, and as @Farcher says, E and J are parallel.

Comment: Side note: $\sigma$ is a tensor not a scalar, so $\vec E$ and $\vec j$ do not point in the same direction if $E$ is not pointing along an eigendirection of $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

The electric field $\vec E$ is normal to the surface of a conductor in the limit that the conductivity is large, $\sigma\to\infty$.  If the conductivity were infinite, any electric field would cause the internal charges to accelerate (i.e. feel a force) in the direction of the field, until the field (and the corresponding force) vanished.

Conductivity has an *enormous* dynamic range.  A nice problem for you to see the effect is long parallel copper wires connecting a DC voltage source with a remote load. Pick any diameter of wire and any separation between the wires.  This is a type of capacitor, where the "capacative voltage" is approximately the voltage from the DC source; you can use the standard formula for the field from an infinite straight wire to find the charge stored on each wire and the electric field between them.  (In fact commercial sellers of cables advertise the capacitance of a cable per unit length.)  If there is current flowing in the wire there will be a voltage drop between the voltage source and the load; you can use Ohm's Law and the conductance to find the electric field inside the wire.  I haven't done the problem but I bet for any reasonable geometry you'll find that the perpendicular field at the wire surface is more than a thousand times stronger than the parallel field inside the wire.